# My model got a loss value of 0, but it just classifies all the input into the same class, what's wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I trained this model to classify the images in the dataset fashion-mnist. When the weights have not been trained the loss value seems normal, but after the first epoch, the loss reduces to 0, and all the input images are classified into class 0.

If regularization added, the weights update slower, but eventually get the same result, say all the images classified to class 0 with a loss value of 0.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

EPOCH = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 30
DATA_SIZE = 60000
REGULARIZER = 0.001


def main():
    fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

    train_images = train_images / 255.0
    test_images = test_images / 255.0

    train_labels = train_labels.reshape((60000, 1))
    train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 784))

    test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 784))
    judge_labels = test_labels.reshape((10000, 1))

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 784))
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 1))

    w1 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(784 * 24).reshape([784, 24]) * 10, dtype=tf.float32)
    # tf.add_to_collection('losses', tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(REGULARIZER)(w1))
    w2 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(24 * 24).reshape([24, 24]) * 10, dtype=tf.float32)
    # tf.add_to_collection('losses', tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(REGULARIZER)(w2))
    w3 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(24 * 10).reshape([24, 10]) * 10, dtype=tf.float32)
    # tf.add_to_collection('losses', tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(REGULARIZER)(w3))

    bias1 = tf.constant(1, shape=(24,), dtype=tf.float32)
    bias2 = tf.constant(1, shape=(24,), dtype=tf.float32)

    y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, w1) + bias1)
    y2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(y1, w2) + bias2)

    y = tf.matmul(y2, w3)

    predict = tf.argmax(y, axis=1)

    y_spy = tf.nn.softmax(y, axis=1)

    ce = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.argmax(y_, 1), logits=y)
    # loss = tf.reduce_mean(ce) + tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'))
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(ce)
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init_op)

        print('current out loss: ', end='')
        print(sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: test_images, y_: judge_labels}))
        pre = sess.run(predict, feed_dict={x: test_images})
        miss = pre - test_labels
        print('right number: ', end='')
        print((np.sum(miss == 0)))

        for epoch in range(EPOCH):
            for i in range(DATA_SIZE // BATCH_SIZE):
                start = i * BATCH_SIZE
                end = (i + 1) * BATCH_SIZE
                _ = sess.run([train_step], feed_dict={x: train_images[start:end],
                                                                                                y_: train_labels[start:end]})
            print('epochs %d :' % epoch)
            print('current in loss: ', end='')
            print(sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: train_images[start:end],
                                            y_: train_labels[start:end]}))
            print('current out loss: ', end='')
            print(sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: test_images, y_: judge_labels}))
            miss = sess.run(predict, feed_dict={x: test_images}) - test_labels
            print('right number: ', end='')
            print((np.sum(miss == 0)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mistake 1:** Loss function should be

```
ce = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.reshape(y_, [-1]), logits=y)
```

because labels are flat values for this loss function. (change y placeholder to int32 type)

**Mistake 2:** The weight are initialled to very large values.

`GradientDescentOptimizer` is very slow optimizer. Use `AdamOptimizer` instead

Fixed code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

EPOCH = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 64
DATA_SIZE = 60000
REGULARIZER = 0.001


def main():
    fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

    train_images = train_images / 255.0
    test_images = test_images / 255.0

    train_labels = train_labels.reshape((60000, 1))
    train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 784))

    test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 784))
    judge_labels = test_labels.reshape((10000, 1))

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 784))
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None, 1))

    w1 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(784 * 24).reshape([784, 24]), dtype=tf.float32)
    # tf.add_to_collection('losses', tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(REGULARIZER)(w1))
    w2 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(24 * 24).reshape([24, 24]), dtype=tf.float32)
    # tf.add_to_collection('losses', tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(REGULARIZER)(w2))
    w3 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(24 * 10).reshape([24, 10]), dtype=tf.float32)
    # tf.add_to_collection('losses', tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(REGULARIZER)(w3))

    bias1 = tf.constant(1, shape=(24,), dtype=tf.float32)
    bias2 = tf.constant(1, shape=(24,), dtype=tf.float32)

    y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, w1) + bias1)
    y2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(y1, w2) + bias2)

    y = tf.matmul(y2, w3)

    predict = tf.argmax(y, axis=1)

    y_spy = tf.nn.softmax(y, axis=1)

    ce = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.reshape(y_, [-1]), logits=y)
    # loss = tf.reduce_mean(ce) + tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'))
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(ce)
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init_op)

        print('current out loss: ', end='')
        print(sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: test_images, y_: judge_labels}))
        pre = sess.run(predict, feed_dict={x: test_images})
        miss = pre - test_labels
        print('right number: ', end='')
        print((np.sum(miss == 0)))

        for epoch in range(EPOCH):
            for i in range(DATA_SIZE // BATCH_SIZE):
                start = i * BATCH_SIZE
                end = (i + 1) * BATCH_SIZE
                _ = sess.run([train_step], feed_dict={x: train_images[start:end],
                             y_: train_labels[start:end]})
            print('epochs %d :' % epoch)
            print('current in loss: ', end='')
            print(sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: train_images[start:end],
                                            y_: train_labels[start:end]}))
            print('current out loss: ', end='')
            print(sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: test_images, y_: judge_labels}))
            miss = sess.run(predict, feed_dict={x: test_images}) - test_labels
            print('right number: ', end='')
            print((np.sum(miss == 0)))

            miss = sess.run(predict, feed_dict={x: test_images})
            print (miss[0:10], test_labels[0:10])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output (selective):

```
...
Sample predictions: [9 2 4 3 2 4 4 4 7 7], Actual: [9 2 1 1 6 1 4 6 5 7]
...
Sample predictions: [9 2 1 1 6 1 4 6 1 7], Actual: [9 2 1 1 6 1 4 6 5 7]
...
Sample predictions: [7 2 1 1 6 1 4 6 1 7], Actual: [9 2 1 1 6 1 4 6 5 7]
...
Sample predictions: [9 2 1 1 6 1 4 6 1 7], Actual: [9 2 1 1 6 1 4 6 5 7]
...
```

**Code with train, validation loss and train, validation accuracy and shuffling train data for each epoch**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score

EPOCH = 30
BATCH_SIZE = 64
DATA_SIZE = 60000
REGULARIZER = 0.001

def main():
    fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

    train_images = train_images / 255.0
    test_images = test_images / 255.0

    train_labels = train_labels.reshape((60000, 1))
    train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 784))

    test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 784))
    judge_labels = test_labels.reshape((10000, 1))

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 784))
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None, 1))

    w1 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(784 * 24).reshape([784, 24]), dtype=tf.float32)
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(REGULARIZER)(w1))
    w2 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(24 * 24).reshape([24, 24]), dtype=tf.float32)
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(REGULARIZER)(w2))
    w3 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(24 * 10).reshape([24, 10]), dtype=tf.float32)
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(REGULARIZER)(w3))

    bias1 = tf.constant(1, shape=(24,), dtype=tf.float32)
    bias2 = tf.constant(1, shape=(24,), dtype=tf.float32)

    y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, w1) + bias1)
    y2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(y1, w2) + bias2)

    y = tf.matmul(y2, w3)

    predict = tf.argmax(y, axis=1)

    ce = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.reshape(y_, [-1]), logits=y)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(ce)
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init_op)

        idx = np.arange(DATA_SIZE)

        for epoch in range(EPOCH):
            train_loss = list()
            train_predict = list()
            np.random.shuffle(idx)

            train_images = train_images[idx]
            train_labels = train_labels[idx]

            for i in range(DATA_SIZE // BATCH_SIZE):
                start = i * BATCH_SIZE
                end = (i + 1) * BATCH_SIZE
                _, loss_, p_ = sess.run([train_step, loss, predict], feed_dict={x: train_images[start:end],
                             y_: train_labels[start:end]})
                train_loss.append(loss_)
                train_predict.extend(p_)


            test_loss, test_predict = sess.run([loss, predict], feed_dict={x: test_images,
                             y_: judge_labels})

            print ("Epoch: {}, Train Loss: {:.3f}, Test Loss: {:.3f},"\
                   "Train Acc: {:.3f}, Test Acc: {:.3f}".format(
                    epoch+1, np.mean(train_loss), test_loss,
                accuracy_score(train_labels[0:len(train_predict)], train_predict),
                accuracy_score(judge_labels, test_predict)))  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
....
Epoch: 27, Train Loss: 0.842, Test Loss: 1.015,Train Acc: 0.816, Test Acc: 0.798
Epoch: 28, Train Loss: 0.832, Test Loss: 0.880,Train Acc: 0.816, Test Acc: 0.806
Epoch: 29, Train Loss: 0.788, Test Loss: 0.886,Train Acc: 0.820, Test Acc: 0.805
Epoch: 30, Train Loss: 0.704, Test Loss: 0.742,Train Acc: 0.826, Test Acc: 0.815
```

Comment: thank u very much! this really solved my problem. I printed the value tf.argmax(y_, 1), which proves to be all zeros. And the data type of y_ is wrong.

Comment: @nuisance glad to know it helped. Please accept the answer (only) if it solved your question :) [How to Accept Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work/65088#65088)

Comment: yes, the model started to fit the data, but there is still one more bug in the code. the test loss computed by the code above is wrong. when the model get overfitted, the in loss nad out loss all get near zero, while the correct number is quite low.